# Fine-tuning or Prompt Engineering or both?

Tags: fine-tuning, prompt

We have a dataset of legal cases, academic papers etc which we will load into a vector database. We want to develop an agent that will allow a user to enter a specific legal issue, the agent then will search for all related documents (or portions of documents) and provide the user with a summary of each along with the citation. The responses should only be based on our domain.
Can this be done with prompt engineering? Would fine-tuning help the quality of the responses? Anything else I should be investigating? TIA

Answer (score 1):

I am completing a master's degree in artificial intelligence.I am researching this field. Initially, try training using techniques like QLora, which was released this week. test distillation techniques and also try fine-tuning. Afterwards, you will need to add a control extern. From my perspective, they could have a model observing the conversation, similar to how ChatGPT functions, or they could use keyword analysis with a smaller model.